# How to do custom trace in production / QA environment?

Tags: site, logging, issue-tracking

My sharepoint site is in production/ QA so now i need to do some trace activity to find the logs. Instead of using log file i need ot have seperate trace. what king of approach i need to use to achive this?. we dont have acesss to the log file to see it in production thats why i am following this option.
My idea:
So when ever my code breaking it will go to catch statement so i need to call one method that will update one hidden list of the site with th log details. But the problem here is all have rights to see the list its not good, Also if we have more issue in clde then the new item will getting added to the list it will be performace issue.

Is there any other best idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the ULS system to write your entries( http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/07/07/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-the-usage-of-sharepoint-2010-uls-logging.aspx ). Alternatively you could even create your own category( http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/) and monitor it ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2009/12/18/sharepoint-2010-logging-improvements-part-1.aspx).